# Unable to open Outlook Notes items after creating using graph api

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to create new note in outlook using graph and it increases the count on outlook 365 web. But I am unable to open these notes items. below is the syntax i am using. Please let me know if i am missing something thanks in advance.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/notes/messages
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACHCosUWr4XTJq6SF8dEwnxAAADJnO1\"",
    "id": "AAMkADQyNjE5ZDY0LWVkNzQtNGFhNi05NTYzLWJkNjQwMzM2ZTEzNQBGAAAAAAC3cPTGmC31SIR4_3GZ-iOkBwCHCosUWr4XTJq6SF8dEwnxAAAAAAERAACHCosUWr4XTJq6SF8dEwnxAAADKRJmAAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2023-03-31T05:57:34Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-03-31T06:43:12Z",
    "changeKey": "CQAAABYAAACHCosUWr4XTJq6SF8dEwnxAAADJnO1",
    "categories": [],
    "receivedDateTime": "2023-03-31T05:59:09Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2023-03-31T05:57:34Z",
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "internetMessageId": "<PN0P287MB063006EDCDFEBA2259E57A40EF8F9@PN0P287MB0630.INDP287.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>",
    "subject": "Test-4 with content",
    "bodyPreview": "Test-3 with contentOn-page optimization is the action that we apply directly to our webpage to increase its ranking on the search result page.On page SEO Factor  *   Website should be crawlable, User friendly URLs, Well target content, Image o",
    "importance": "normal",
    "parentFolderId": "AAMkADQyNjE5ZDY0LWVkNzQtNGFhNi05NTYzLWJkNjQwMzM2ZTEzNQAuAAAAAAC3cPTGmC31SIR4_3GZ-iOkAQCHCosUWr4XTJq6SF8dEwnxAAAAAAERAAA=",
    "conversationId": "AAQkADQyNjE5ZDY0LWVkNzQtNGFhNi05NTYzLWJkNjQwMzM2ZTEzNQAQAGiuY5VCyHRPNhnrEPSCfW0=",
    "conversationIndex": "AQHZY5WwjK0aw5xdoka025ThJey98Q==",
    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
    "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
    "isRead": true,
    "isDraft": false,
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADQyNjE5ZDY0LWVkNzQtNGFhNi05NTYzLWJkNjQwMzM2ZTEzNQBGAAAAAAC3cPTGmC31SIR4%2B3GZ%2FiOkBwCHCosUWr4XTJq6SF8dEwnxAAAAAAERAACHCosUWr4XTJq6SF8dEwnxAAADKRJmAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
    "inferenceClassification": "focused",
    "unsubscribeData": [],
    "unsubscribeEnabled": false,
    "mentionsPreview": null,
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><style><!--ul{list-style:none}html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, li{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline}--></style></head><body id=\"NotesClientContent\"><div><p dir=\"ltr\">Test-3 with content</p><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><p dir=\"ltr\">On-page optimization is the action that we apply directly to our webpage to increase its ranking on the search result page.</p><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; text-decoration:underline\">On page SEO Factor</span></p><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><ul dir=\"ltr\" style=\"padding:0px 20px\"><li style=\"list-style-type:disc\"><p dir=\"ltr\">Website should be crawlable, User friendly URLs, Well target content, Image optimization, Readability, CTR (Click through Rate), Mobile friendliness, Keyword optimization, Quality outbound link, Website structure, etc.</p></li></ul><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; text-decoration:underline\">Working process of Search engines</span></p><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><ul dir=\"ltr\" style=\"padding:0px 20px\"><li style=\"list-style-type:disc\"><p dir=\"ltr\">When a website publish then search engine crawler/spider crawled the site and add/indexed in local server along with category like news, sports, images etc. after that manage to Main server. Now algorithm work on these index and provides the ranking that user search on Google and other <span style=\"text-decoration:line-through\">search engines</span>.</p></li></ul></div></body></html>"
    },
    "toRecipients": [],
    "ccRecipients": [],
    "bccRecipients": [],
    "replyTo": [],
    "flag": {
        "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
    }
}
```

Count is increasing every time when I am creating new items but unable to view those items in outlook web.

I tried above sample code and able to create notes in outlook. But it's not opening. Is any extended property need to be set or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Take a look at a note with OutlookSpy (I am its author - https://www.dimastr.com/outspy - click IMessage button) or MFCMAPI (https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) to compare good and bad items and see what's missing/different.

Comment: The other way around is to get existing items in Outlook and find the difference without any tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying quite a few calculated fields that can be returned in a `GET` request, but should never be specified in a `POST` request: `"@odata.etag", "id", "createdDateTime", "lastModifiedDateTime", "changeKey", "internetMessageId", "bodyPreview", "parentFolderId", "conversationId", "conversationIndex", "webLink", "unsubscribeData", "unsubscribeEnabled", "mentionsPreview", "hasAttachments"` etc.

Most importantly, you are not setting the `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS` MAPI property, which means it will be defaulted to `IPM.Note` rather than `IPM.StickyNote`

The following payload worked fine for me in "Graph Request Pad" in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author):

```json
{
    "categories": [],
    "receivedDateTime": "2023-03-31T05:59:09Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2023-03-31T05:57:34Z",
    "subject": "Test-6 with content",
    "importance": "normal",
    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
    "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
    "isRead": true,
    "isDraft": false,
    "inferenceClassification": "focused",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><style><!--ul{list-style:none}html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, li{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline}--></style></head><body id=\"NotesClientContent\"><div><p dir=\"ltr\">Test-3 with content</p><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><p dir=\"ltr\">On-page optimization is the action that we apply directly to our webpage to increase its ranking on the search result page.</p><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; text-decoration:underline\">On page SEO Factor</span></p><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><ul dir=\"ltr\" style=\"padding:0px 20px\"><li style=\"list-style-type:disc\"><p dir=\"ltr\">Website should be crawlable, User friendly URLs, Well target content, Image optimization, Readability, CTR (Click through Rate), Mobile friendliness, Keyword optimization, Quality outbound link, Website structure, etc.</p></li></ul><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; text-decoration:underline\">Working process of Search engines</span></p><p dir=\"ltr\"></p><ul dir=\"ltr\" style=\"padding:0px 20px\"><li style=\"list-style-type:disc\"><p dir=\"ltr\">When a website publish then search engine crawler/spider crawled the site and add/indexed in local server along with category like news, sports, images etc. after that manage to Main server. Now algorithm work on these index and provides the ranking that user search on Google and other <span style=\"text-decoration:line-through\">search engines</span>.</p></li></ul></div></body></html>"
    },
    "toRecipients": [],
    "ccRecipients": [],
    "bccRecipients": [],
    "replyTo": [],
    "flag": {
        "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
    },
   "singleValueExtendedProperties":[
     {"id":"String 0x1a",
      "value":"IPM.StickyNote"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now it's working for me. One more question, does Outlook redemption supports modern authentication for office 365?

Comment: Hello Dmitry, It's working fine for admin mailbox. But still showing the same problem when I am trying to post a new stickynote to user's mailbox.

Comment: If you already have Outlook running, Redemption can piggyback on existing Outlook connection - create an instance of the RDOSession object, set its MAPIOBJECT property to Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the good and bad sticky notes to see what's missing?

Comment: Yes, I tried but unable to find the problem because the same syntax is working while creating stickynotes in admin mailbox.

Comment: So if you look at the good and bad notes with OutlookSpy, you don't see any differences in the IMessage window?

Comment: i am not sure how to see good and bad notes with graph api

Comment: You don't need to look at the notes with Graph - as a test, look at the notes in Outlook with OutlookSpy (click IMessage), or the standalone MFCMAPI. You want to see the low level MAPI data.